# Alamofire Swift 3 + PHP upload image not working

Tags: php, swift, alamofire

I am trying to upload an image using Alamofire and PHP on my server, I checked all the different questions on here but for some reason it wont work. I have tested my PHP file with HTML and it succeeded in uploading an image, so it narrows down to my swift code.

Swift:

```
    let URL = "http://example.com/post_pic.php"
    let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageView.image!, 1)


    Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { (multipartFormData) in
        multipartFormData.append(imageData!, withName: "imageFile", mimeType: "image/jpeg")
    }, to:URL)
    { (result) in
        switch result {
        case .success(let upload, _, _):

            upload.uploadProgress(closure: { (Progress) in
                print("Upload Progress: \(Progress.fractionCompleted)")
            })

            upload.responseJSON { response in
                print(response.request)  // original URL request
                print(response.response) // URL response
                print(response.data)     // server data
                print(response.result)   // result of response serialization
                //                        self.showSuccesAlert()
                //self.removeImage("frame", fileExtension: "txt")
                if let JSON = response.result.value {
                    print("JSON: \(JSON)")
                }

            }

        case .failure(let encodingError):
            print("Failure:")
            print(encodingError)
        }

    }
```

PHP:

```
if(isset($_FILES['imageFile'])){
    $errors= array();
    $file_name = $_FILES['imageFile']['name'];
    $file_size =$_FILES['imageFile']['size'];
    $file_tmp =$_FILES['imageFile']['tmp_name'];
    $file_type=$_FILES['imageFile']['type'];
    $file_ext=strtolower(end(explode('.',$_FILES['imageFile']['name'])));
    print_r($_FILES['imageFile']);

    if(empty($errors)==true){
      move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"images/".$file_name);
    }
    else
    {
      echo '{"response":"file_move_error"}';
    }   
}
else
{
        echo '{"response":"file_error"}';

}
```

The response I get is:

```
 Optional(<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x17022df20> { URL: http://example.com/post_pic.php } { 
      status code: 200, headers {
     Connection = "Keep-Alive";
     "Content-Length" = 25;
     "Content-Type" = "application/json";
     Date = "Wed, 25 Jan 2017 10:16:29 GMT";
     "Keep-Alive" = "timeout=5, max=100";
     Server = "Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)";
     "X-Powered-By" = "PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.20";
 } })
      Optional(25 bytes)
      SUCCESS
      JSON: {
          response = "file_error";
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

I can use this code into my app

```
let URL = "http://example.com/post_pic.php"
let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageView.image!, 1)


    upload(multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
                    multipartFormData.append(imageData!, withName: "imageFile", fileName: "file.jpg", mimeType: "image/jpeg")
        },
            to: URL, method: .post,
            encodingCompletion: { encodingResult in

                switch encodingResult {
                case .success(let upload, _, _):


                    upload.validate()
                    upload.responseJSON { response in


                        if response.result.error != nil {
                            print("failure")
                            UIAlertView(title: "Fail", message: "Please retry again.", delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "Ok").show()
                        } else {
                            print("success")


                        }
                    }
                case .failure(let encodingError):
                    print(encodingError)

                }
        }
        )
```

Comment: `multipartFormData.append(imageData!, withName: "imageFile", fileName=xxxx.jpg, mimeType: "image/jpeg")`

Comment: its:
multipartFormData.append(imageData!, withName: "imageFile", fileName: "xxxx.jpg", mimeType: "image/jpeg)

Comment: You know that your php code, is incorrect? the $_FILES parameter is incorrect, and most of the variables are uninitialized?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133990/discussion-between-ronak-and-masterwizard).